# How to implement an interactive tooltip in Angular

Tags: angular, user-interface, tooltip, primeng

I would like to have an interactive tooltip in my application - I have some pretty long names in a table - I want to display an on-hover tooltip with the full name. I want the tooltip to be clickable, so the user can click a button to copy the full name to the clipboard.

My application uses PrimeNg, however I tried some other tooltips - the problem is that I can't find a way to prevent the tooltip from hiding when the user moves the cursor from the paragraph onto the tooltip - mouseleave event fires. I didn't find any help in PrimeNg documentation.

Any suggestions how could I implement that from scratch in Angular?

Comment: try toast: 
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/toast/examples

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to [primeNg overlay panel](https://primefaces.org/primeng/overlaypanel).

This is an [example](https://primeng-overlaypanel-demo-ayrthm.stackblitz.io/)